# SET IDENTITY_INSERT TableName ON does not work on Entity Framework Core 2.2

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, aspnetboilerplate

I'm trying to insert a record into a table that has the ID auto generated.
For this reason this is my code:

```
using (var context = new DbContext(GetConnection().Options))
{
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Customers ON;");
    context.SaveChanges();
    context.Customers.Add(customer);
    context.SaveChanges();
    context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Customers OFF;");
}
```

But the exception is always the same:

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I also tried to execute the command `SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Customers ON` manually in SQL Server Management Studio and after execute the code above but the same exception is thrown.

Why?

Comment: ***WHY*** do you need to supply explicit values? The whole point of an `IDENTITY` column is that you **don't have to** worry about providing proper values - SQL Server will handle that for you .....

Comment: agreed, your requirement doesn't really make sense. Why can't you just let the database generate the value? If you don't want that for some reason, then don't use an IDENTITY column

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, Entity Framework will throw an error that you got when you try to insert value for identity column. Even if you enable `identity_insert`, it will be in database level not Entity Framework.

To overcome this, you already done the first step. But as a second step, you need to tell Entity Framework this field be insertable. You can do this with 2 different way.

1. Go to your model class, and add `[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]` to your identity column. With this method you can insert record with identity column, without depending on transaction.
2. Also, you can execute your whole code in the same connection. This way, EF Core will not throw an error when you try to insert your record. Please check following code.

   ```
   using (var db = new Context())
   {
       db.Categories.Add(new Category
       {
           Id = 5,
           Name = "test"
       });

       db.Database.OpenConnection();
       try
       {
           db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Categories ON;");
           db.SaveChanges();
           db.Database.ExecuteSqlRaw("SET IDENTITY_INSERT dbo.Categories OFF;");
       }
       finally
       {
           db.Database.CloseConnection();
       }
   }
   ```

**UPDATE**

`HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` can also be used when working only with Entity Framework. Entity Framework Core Fluent API doesn't have implementation for `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)`.

Comment: Hi @Serdar, i can' t find the ```HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)``` in my mappings. ( I mean ```modelBuilder.Entity<Customer>().Property(x => x.Id). ?? ```)

Comment: And the ```[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]``` i can' t insert that because the Id field is inherited from an abstract class

Comment: Looks like there is no support for `HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)` in EF Core. I have another suggestion which will be more clean. Please check the update.

Comment: If i use the BeginTransaction() like your implementation no error is shown but no record is saved in DB. If i add ```tran.commit()``` before the ```db.SaveChanges()```
it shows the same error: Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Customers' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Comment: I believe I made a mistake and whole didn't execute in the same transaction. You can achieve same outcome with executing your whole code in the same connection. I updated the code in the answer. Please have a look. It's tested and definitely working.

Comment: It works! But i used ExecuteSqlCommand() instead of ExecuteSqlRaw(), becasue i can' t find it.

Thank you so much Serdar.

Comment: but what to do if you have a lot of entities? you cannot add the wrapper for all of them